# Grab region by its aria-labelledby text

Tags: html, react-testing-library, testing-library

I have this `role="region"` div which is has an `aria-labelledby` attribute mapped to a heading inside the div.

HTML

```
<div role="region" aria-labelledby="Year 1">
  <div id="Year 1">Year 1</div>
</div>
```

Problem is by using the following query I can't grab it by the heading's id.

```
screen.getByRole('region', { name: 'Year 1' });
```

Even the heading content is the same as the `id` and still it doesn't work.

The only way is to I found is to use `aria-label` on the region div but that doesn't quite map to the heading at that point. You may test it in the [testing-playground](https://testing-playground.com/).

Is there a way to use my original query somehow?

Comment: Why not just drop the second argument and do `screen.getByRole('region')`;? Is it because you have multiple elements with the same role? Also would be helpful to know what are you trying to test/assert - Maybe there is a different way to go about it

Comment: There are multiple `region`s and it's better for both accessibility and testing, grabbing the right element.

Comment: Is that because "Year 1" isn't a valid element ID (because it has spaces), so the aria-labelledby can't find that element to get its label? If I change the IDs to something like "Year1", then `screen.getByRole('region', { name: 'Year 1' });` will work for me in the playground.

Answer (score 0):

Your ID — "Year 1" — has spaces, which isn't valid. From the [DOM spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#global-attributes:the-id-attribute-2) (emphasis added):

> When specified on [HTML elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#html-elements), the `id` attribute value must be unique amongst all the [IDs](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-id) in the element's [tree](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-tree) and must contain at least one character. **The value must not contain any [ASCII whitespace](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#ascii-whitespace).**

In addition, `aria-labelledby` takes a space-separated list of IDs (on the assumption that IDs won't have spaces). From MDN [aria-labelledby](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-labelledby#benefits_and_drawbacks):

> The aria-labelledby property takes as value a space-separated id reference list, which means you can combine more than one element into a single accessible name.

This means that using `aria-labelledby="Year 1"` cannot reference your `<div id="Year 1">Year 1</div>` element to get its label, so your region actually has no accessible name, which you can see in DevTools:

[image: region has no accessible name, invalid source]

---

Once you give it a valid ID and reference that with `aria-labelledby`, then it will have an accessible name ("Year 1", the actual text content of the inner div):

[image]

Once that happens, then your role query can filter by name as expected:

```
screen.getByRole('region', { name: 'Year 1' });
```